# Scanf with optional text

Tags: c, file, matrix, text, scanf

I'm trying to read a .txt file, which contains a name and a last name in the first line and below contains an array

The problem is that the first line may or may not one letter A in brackets like this: [A].

for instance:

Jose Perez [A] or may have jose perez

When I run here mentioned code, if the first line does not contain a [A] performs a shift of values, for example the value of the matrix [1] [1] is up as tester and insert a 0 at the end to complete the matrix.

Here is a sample of what gives the code when there is a [A] in the first line and when not

```
FILE* text=NULL;
    text=fopen(archivo,"r");
    char name[100];
    char last_name [100];
    char verifier [10];
    int matriz[6][4];
    int i  ;
    int lu,ma,mi,ju,vi;
    if (text == NULL) {
    }
    else {
        fscanf(text,"%s %s %s [^\n]",name, last_name, verifier);
        for( i= 0; i<7;i++){
            fscanf(text,"%d %d %d %d %d [^\n]",&lu, &ma, &mi,&ju,&vi);
            matriz[i][0] = lu;
            matriz[i][1] = ma;
            matriz[i][2] = mi;
            matriz[i][3] = ju;
            matriz[i][4] = vi;
        }
Result:
    Jose Perez 1 
    0 0 0 0 0 
    1 0 1 0 1 
    0 1 1 1 1 
    0 1 1 0 0 
    1 0 0 0 0 
    1 1 1 0 0 
    1 0 1 0 0 
    Juan Perez A 
    1 0 1 1 1 
    0 0 1 1 1 
    0 0 1 0 1 
    0 0 1 1 1 
    1 0 1 0 1 
    0 0 1 1 1 
    0 1 1 1 0
```

As could be solved?

Comment: `matriz[6][4]` should be `matriz[7][5]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    char line[80], fname[16], lname[16], third[4];
    fgets(line, 80, fp)
    if (sscanf(line, "%s %s %s\n", 
              fname, lname, third) == 3 && strcmp(third, "[A]") == 0)
        // the line has a [A] at the end
    else if (sscanf(line, "%s %s\n", fname, lname) == 2)
        // the line does not have a [A] at the end
    else
        fprintf(stderr, "Invalid line");
```

`fgets` reads the next line from the file. If it is not null, we check the return value of `sscanf`. It returns the number of items parsed. So, on success it should return 3. If it contains a `[A]` at the end of the line, the `third` variable should compare equal to `[A]`.

After all this, we can proceed to read the array.

Comment: The problem is that I have to take it anyway read the line, so the next fscanf continue with the next. You know any command to read the line but then to take fscanf reread the first again?

Comment: Thats why i first get the line with `fgets`, and then parse the string with `sscanf`. If I used `fscanf` directly that line would be read and i would have to `fseek` back to the start.

Comment: There is no point to the `'\n'` in the format `"%s %s %s\n` or `"%s %s\n"`.  It gives a false sense that nothing follows the last `'%s"`

Answer (score 1):

Since your verifier is always a single character, you can let `scanf` do the work. In the example below it will stop scanning if the opening bracket does not exist, but get the verifier character otherwise:

```
char name[100];
char last_name [100];
char verifier = 0;
int n = fscanf("%s %s [%c]", name, last_name, &verifier);
```

If `n == 2` there was no verifier, if `n == 3` there was a verifier, and in any other case, there was an error.

Comment: The last `']'` serves  no purpose to to verify.  The scan would report 3 if the `']'` was there or not.

Comment: @chux The `']'` is needed because if it is not consumed, `scanf` will not be able to parse the subsequent data.

Comment: True the `"]"` affects the _next_ assessment.  But a verifier the tests the _current_ line is better.